# Why this code with NSJSONSerialization always crashes?

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

```
//
//  main.m
//  ASADeepDictionary
//
//  Created by AndrewShmig on 3/10/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 AndrewShmig. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ASADeepDictionary.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
 @autoreleasepool {

NSDictionary *dic = @{@"key":@"value"};
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

[archiver encodeObject:dic];
[archiver finishEncoding];

id json = [NSJSONSerialization
           dataWithJSONObject:data
           options:0
           error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", json);

 }

 return 0;
}
```

Error I am getting is:

```
2013-03-10 19:48:13.420 ASADeepDictionary[9451:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught    exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89fb70a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88fac3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89fb6e7c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff848bb49d +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 249
    4   ASADeepDictionary                   0x0000000100001051 main + 321
    5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff84bfd7e1 start + 0
    6   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument must be an `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray`, not an `NSData`. You seem to be misunderstanding what this method does. It **serializes** the passed-in object, it doesn't *parse* it.

Comment: Suppose I send an NSString then it should return me an error but its crashing??

Comment: @user1010819 Why should it return an error? You violated the constraints (you passed a string instead of a dictionary).

Comment: Ya i got that!!.Now I am checking if it is a valid JSOn object before passing it to the method.But when it will return error.I assumed that if don't pass a proper JSON object it will return me an error.

Comment: @user1010819 Don't assume things - read the documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"key":@"value"};

id json = [NSJSONSerialization
           dataWithJSONObject:dic
           options:0
           error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[json bytes]]);
```