# why this code with nsjsonserialization always crashes only on running on actual device.Its fine in simulator

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

[image]Please refer the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324188/why-this-code-with-nsjsonserialization-always-crashes)

I am getting the crash only when I test it on actual device. Simulator works fine. Please help

```
-(void)setFormatForAnswer:(NSDictionary*)answerDict withJsonString:(NSString*)json{ 
NSData *jsonDatanew = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:     [answerDict copy] options:0 error:nil]; 
NSString *jsonnew = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDatanew encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
answerTobeReplacedInDB = jsonnew;
NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json":json};
parameters = @{@"survey_answer":answersDict};
```

[self submitSurveyAnswer];
 }

Comment: please post the crash log!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I have attached the screenshot and this was the code before-(void)setFormatForAnswer:(NSDictionary*)answerDict withJsonString:(NSString*)json{
    NSData *jsonDatanew = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[answerDict copy] options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *jsonnew = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDatanew encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    answerTobeReplacedInDB = jsonnew;
    
    NSDictionary *answersDict = @{@"answers_json":json};
    parameters = @{@"survey_answer":answersDict};
    [self submitSurveyAnswer];
    
}

Comment: update the question with the code please, hard to read the code in the comment section

Comment: Is `answerDict` `nil` or `answerDict` not a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray`?

Comment: nope! it had values all the time. I did LOG the jsonDatanew and it had values.But maybe its because of improper format and the method was called because of some notification being registered in the bg.

Comment: If you launch it with XCode to your Device, what's the full error message?